# why does the information on the email I receive from the nodemailer say undefined?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, contact-form

I have two post requests so my app.js file has two handlers.
One for the documentation submission and one for the contact form. but the email I receive from the contact information on the email I receive says undefined [EMAIL CONTENTS NOT DEFINED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5qmk.png)

Here is what my code app.js file looks like:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer'); // handling docs and images (attachments)
const fs = require('fs'); // used to delete files from storing it
//const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); has been deprecated
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

var subject;
var body;
var path;

var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './docs') //storing the file into the folder "docs"
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname)
        } // creating the name of the file to be stored -location + date + original filename
    });

    //handling the upload via multer
    var upload = multer({
        storage: Storage
    }).single('pdf');

    //static folder
    app.use(express.static('public'))

    app.get('/',( req, res) => {
       res.sendFile('/index.html')
    })

    //sending emails via nodemailer
    app.post('/sendemail', (req, res) => {

    //EXCECUTE THIS MIDDLEWARE TO UPLOAD PDF
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.end("Something went wrong")
        } else {
            subject = req.body.subject
            body = req.body.body
    
            path = req.file.path

            console.log(subject)
            console.log(body)
            console.log(path)

            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: '***************',
                port: 465,
                secure: true,
                auth: {
                    user: '*************',
                    pass: '*********',
                },
                tls: {
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
               }
           });

           var mailOptions = {
               from: '"Raborifi Contact Form" ****************',
               to: '**************',
               subject: subject,
               text: body,
               attachments: [
                 {
                    path: path
                 }
              ]
          };

          transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
              if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
              } else {
                  console.log("Email Sent" + info.response)
                  fs.unlink(path, function (err) {
                      if (err) {
                          return res.end(err)
                      } else {
                          console.log("Deleted")
                          return res.redirect('result.html')
                      }
                  })
              }
          });
      }
  });
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
    let output = `
        <p>You have a new contact request</p>
        <h3>Contact Details</h3>
        <ul>  
        <li>Name:${req.body.names}</li>
        <li>Company:${req.body.company}</li>
        <li>Email:${req.body.email}</li>
        <li>Phone:${req.body.phone}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <p>${req.body.message}</p>
    `;

    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: '*************',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: '********',
            pass: '******',
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
});

let mailOptions = {
  from: '"test Contact Form" <test@acjintrodesigns.com>', // sender address
  to: 'test@acjintrodesigns.com', // list of receivers
  subject: 'Contact Request', // Subject line
  text: 'Hello world?', // plain text body
  html: output, // html body
 };

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
           if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  });
  res.redirect('/contact.html');
 });

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("App started on port 3000")
})
```

The body is the form that looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/send" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
            <h2>Contact Form</h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="names">Name and Surname</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="names" name="names" placeholder="Your Name and Surname..">
            </div>
                
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="company">Company</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Your company..">
            </div>
                
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email..">
            </div>
                
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number..">
            </div>

            <p class="full">
                <label for="subject">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="subject" name="message" placeholder="Write something.."
                    style="height:200px"></textarea>
            </p>

        
                <p class="full">
                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </p>
        
            </form>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me I will compensate for your efforts if it works.

Comment: what is in `req.body`?

Comment: its the form.. i have edited my question and inserted the contact form. i realized the bodyParser extended is deprecated so i have edited it to use the express option but still it does the same thing. the email comes back with information as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue thanks to another developer. i had to remove the enctype from my form so taking this out:`enctype = "multipart/form-data"`
and now it works like a boss!